# SAS String to Numeric - '+0000000xx.xxx'

Tags: sas, format

I am extracting data from a database that has all values posted in strings, in the format +000000xx.xxx or -00000xx.xxx . I need to convert these to numeric to operate on.

```
data want;
set have; 
numeric_var = string_var*1;
run;
```

works fine, but, to save compute time and resources on the final running, which will be over a much larger dataset, and in the interest of doing things properly I'd rather do that with a format or informat statement.

```
data want;
set have; 
numeric_var = input(string_var, best8.);
run;
```

seems to output wrong values and to round everything to 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using `best8.` is telling SAS to only consider the first 8 characters of the string, so that's never going to work. You should use just `best.` or possibly `best32.` if you feel you have to pre-specify the length.

However, make sure you run some benchmarks before changing your current simple solution. SAS is already doing a character-to-numeric conversion as part of the `numeric_var = string_var*1;` statement, and is apparently doing it correctly; changing the code to use an informat will not automatically be any faster.

It would be cool if you benchmarked both methods and reported the results back here.

EDIT:

I did some benchmarking on this, out of curiosity. The code and log are below but TL;DR - the informat seems to be very slightly but consistently faster - 7.58 seconds vs 7.83 seconds in the run below on a 50 million observation data set. So the informat method is the way to go, but the 3% performance gain wouldn't be worth refactoring a large program, particularly if you don't have good test coverage to be sure of avoiding regressions.

```
483  * Set small for testing, big for benchmarking;
484  %let obs = 50000000;
485
486  * Generate test data;
487  data testdata;
488    do i = 1 to &obs;
489      numeric = round(ranuni(0)*100, 0.001);
490      char = '+' || put(numeric, z12.3-L);
491      output;
492    end;
493  run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.TESTDATA has 50000000 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           12.55 seconds
      user cpu time       11.41 seconds
      system cpu time     0.84 seconds
      memory              4375.18k
      OS Memory           20784.00k
      Timestamp           12/10/2019 10:36:11 AM
      Step Count                        51  Switch Count  0


494
495  %macro charToNum(in=, method=, obs=);
496
497    * Convert back to numeric;
498    data converted;
499      set &in;
500      %if "&method" = "MULT-BY-ONE" %then %do;
501        converted = char * 1;
502      %end; %else %if "&method" = "INFORMAT" %then %do;
503        converted = input(char, 32.);
504      %end;
505      if converted ne numeric then do;
506        put "ERROR: Conversion failed: " numeric= char= converted=;
507      end;
508    run;
509
510  %mend;
511
512  %charToNum(in = testdata, method = MULT-BY-ONE, obs = &obs);

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by:
      (Line):(Column).
      3:20
NOTE: There were 50000000 observations read from the data set WORK.TESTDATA.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CONVERTED has 50000000 observations and 4 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           7.83 seconds
      user cpu time       5.92 seconds
      system cpu time     1.88 seconds
      memory              14642.84k
      OS Memory           31036.00k
      Timestamp           12/10/2019 10:36:18 AM
      Step Count                        52  Switch Count  0


513  %charToNum(in = testdata, method = INFORMAT, obs = &obs);

NOTE: There were 50000000 observations read from the data set WORK.TESTDATA.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CONVERTED has 50000000 observations and 4 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           7.58 seconds
      user cpu time       5.36 seconds
      system cpu time     2.15 seconds
      memory              14646.18k
      OS Memory           31036.00k
      Timestamp           12/10/2019 10:36:26 AM
      Step Count                        53  Switch Count  0
```

Comment: You are right, adjusting for the number of digits before the decimal did work. I was under the impression (i don't know why), that 8. meant 8 digits to the left of the decimal point initially.
 A simple input statement like num_var = input(string_var, 16.6) did the trick.

I will keep the benchmark thing in mind and see if I can do that. SAS documentation does say that *1 is more cpu intensive, but my dry run dataset is too small to tell.

Comment: Do not include a decimal width in an informat unless you want SAS to divide values without an explicit period by that power of ten. Also no need to limit the length, unless the end of the string needs to be excluded, just use `32.` as the informat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the numbers, use the code below. 
Using compress this way the numbers in the string will keeped.
The first parameter is the name of variable. The second is optional, this case the caracters to be keeped. Third is "k" that means keep.

```
data want;
set have; 
numeric_var = input(compress(string_var,"0123456789","k"), best8.);
run;
```